# Find An Event Based on Date Relative to a Treatment Date

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I am working with some data that is in long-form and trying to use R to manipulate it and prepare it for analysis. Each item has a unique identification (UNIQUE_ID) and a series of events (ex: a, c, d, v) along with corresponding event dates. Moreover, there is a treatment date (TX_DATE).

I am trying to flag a certain event type (c) if, and only if, it occurs after TX_DATE, for each subject. Moreover, I would like to determine the time between treatment (TX_DATE) and the date that the event of interest occurs (c with EVENT_DATE).

Sample Input Data:

```
UNIQUE_ID   EVENT   EVENT_DATE  TX_DATE
       1     a       1/1/1999   1/15/2020
       1     a       1/6/2002   1/15/2020
       1     c       2/2/2020   1/15/2020
       2     v       1/4/1999   7/1/2020
       2     v       1/5/2012   7/1/2020
       2     d       6/7/2020   7/1/2020
       2     c       4/3/1998   7/1/2020
       2     c       8/8/2020   7/1/2020
       2     d       9/5/2010   7/1/2020
       3     a       6/5/1995   6/2/2020
       3     a       9/12/2020  6/2/2020
       4     v       1/6/1998   8/1/2020
       4     v       7/8/2019   8/1/2020
       4     a       9/8/2020   8/1/2020
       4     c       7/6/2020   8/1/2020
```

Sample Output Data:

```
UNIQUE_ID   EVENT   EVENT_DATE  TX_DATE   POST_TX_FLAG  TIME_EVENT_DAYS TIME_EVENT_MONTHS
      1      a       1/1/1999   1/15/2020     0             7684              252.60
      1      a       1/6/2002   1/15/2020     0             6583              216.40
      1      c       2/2/2020   1/15/2020     1               18                0.59
      2      v       1/4/1999   7/1/2020      0             7849              258.02
      2      v       1/5/2012   7/1/2020      0             3100              101.91
      2      d       6/7/2020   7/1/2020      0               24                0.79
      2      c       4/3/1998   7/1/2020      0             8125              267.09
      2      c       8/8/2020   7/1/2020      1               38                1.25
      2      d       9/5/2010   7/1/2020      0             3587              117.92
      3      a       6/5/1995   6/2/2020      0             9129              300.10
      3      a       9/12/2020  6/2/2020      0              102                3.35
      4      v       1/6/1998   8/1/2020      0             8243              270.97
      4      v       7/8/2019   8/1/2020      0              390               12.82
      4      a       9/8/2020   8/1/2020      0               38                1.25
      4      c       7/6/2020   8/1/2020      0               26                0.85
```

Moreover, the data I will be working with may have many events. And I would like to limit the output to the first event after TX_DATE.

Comment: The question is strange if in id 3 and 4 no flag is 1 how do you compute the differences??

Comment: If the flag is 0, then those will be deleted in the analysis. I just figured it would be simpler to not add another conditional. Another way to think about it, that flag is 0 (censored) so could also use the time to censored event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `tidyverse` and `lubridate` packages in R.

Assuming your data is contained in the dataframe `df`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% mutate( EVENT_DATE = mdy(EVENT_DATE),
                 TX_DATE = mdy(TX_DATE),
                 POST_TX_FLAG = EVENT_DATE > TX_DATE,
                 TIME_EVENT_DAYS = time_length(TX_DATE - EVENT_DATE , unit="day"),
                 TIME_EVENT_MONTHS = time_length(TX_DATE - EVENT_DATE , unit="month") )
```

Comment: Hi al_the_man, this does seem to get most of it. But, it does not get the right POST_TX_FLAG. How do we modify your answer to be something like: mydata %>% mutate(EVENT_DATE = mdy(EVENT_DATE),
                 TX_DATE = mdy(TX_DATE),
                 POST_TX_FLAG = ifelse(EVENT=="c" & (EVENT_DATE > TX_DATE), 1, 0),
                 TIME_EVENT_DAYS = time_length(TX_DATE - EVENT_DATE , unit="day"),
                 TIME_EVENT_MONTHS = time_length(TX_DATE - EVENT_DATE , unit="month"))

Comment: Hi @tjquinn87! I tried POST_TX_FLAG = if_else( EVENT == "c" & EVENT_DATE > TX_DATE, 1 , 0 ) it seems to work. Is there any specific cases where it fails?